# Display images knowing their ID

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to use a gallery field add-on to Wordpress' [ACF plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). The add-on is [Navz Photo Gallery](https://wordpress.org/plugins/navz-photo-gallery/). All it does is to give you a way to get the gallery photos' IDs. Now I want to actually display the images.

By calling the following code

```
<?php if ( get_field( 'field_name') ) { ?>
    <img src="<?php the_field( 'field_name' ); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

all I get are the actual IDs, like this:

```
<img src="21,22,23">
```

Does anybody know how to loop thru this group of images and display them individually, not just the ID, but the actual image?

For reference, ACF has an official (paid) gallery add-on, and it displays the attached images like this:

```
<?php $images = get_field('gallery'); if( $images ): ?>
<?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navz has helped me with this:

```
<?php
$images = get_field('fotos_do_projeto'); if( $images ): $images = explode(',', $images); $images = array_filter($images); if( count($images)):
?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): $alt = get_the_title($image); $url = get_post_meta($image, 'field_5802bd6e39e9b_url', true); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo $alt; ?>">
                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image, "thumbnail", false, ['alt' => $alt]); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
    $attachment_id = get_field( 'field_name');
    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id );
    if ( $image_attributes ) : ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>" />
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time